# NodeJs flow error

Tags: node.js

I am new to NodeJs and I have the following code using the nimbel library

```
function createNode(callback){
    exec(console.log("2"),callback);
}

flow.series([
    function(callback){
        console.log("1");
        for (i=0;i<2;i++){
            flow.parallel([
                function(callback){
                  createNode(callback

);
                }
            ],callback);
        }
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log("3");
        callback();
    }
    ]);
```

I want the output from the console to be 1,2,2,3 but the last function that outputs 3 is not being called any ideas ?

Comment: Well first of all, I would start by having useful names for my callbacks (at least when they are all meshed together with this type of code). It would appear that your final callback on the `parallel` method is never invoked so I'd start with investigating your `exec` calls to make sure they are definitely triggering the passed callback.

Comment: passing `console.log("2")` to exec is almost certainly not what you want.